# How Upload My .War file in server

Tags: java, server

I new to deploying project n server.How to deploy my war file virtual private server(VPS), and how to extract .
my war file working in my local pc .Any one please tell me the steps to deploying a project

Comment: You can use FileZilla to upload war file,there are plenty of other tools as well also your server provider also give you option to upload files.

Answer (score 0):

If your server is used Tomcat to deploy your war file,you may follow these steps:

1. Open your terminal ,and send your war file to you VPS by scp.
2. Login in you VPS and use `w3m` to open tomcat management page,you will find `Tomcat Manager`,just enter.
3. Then you can select your war file and deploy it to you host.And Tomcat will extract the war file for you and put it in the correct path.

Comment: i deploy my war file in tomcat cat manager in server it will working fine.             i will getting output like this 43.68.198.3/example but when i am typing my example.com it will show Http error 404 file not found errror

Comment: @pramodK Maybe you need to check is there any firewall in your host or tomcat port is open for you to access.I don't use VPS ,but I think there should have a configuration to solve this problem.

Comment: it working but after uploading my data into my server it will show like thisThe requested URL /uploadServlet was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.2.31 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.31 OpenSSL/1.0.1e-fips mod_jk/1.2.37 mod_bwlimited/1.4 Server at shopvend.in Port 80@uestcfei

Answer (score -1):

For extracting war file, In netbeans

When you right click your project and select clean and build, then right click again and deploy. .war file will be created inside dist folder of your project.

for detailed explanation check [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dhiPDXSj48c)

Comment: file successes fully uploaded in my server,  it will getting my page but when i am uploaded my details into my database it will passing null values